# Copy property values by mapping property names

Tags: c#, properties, mapping, cloning

I have two LINQ table objects calls Orders and ImportedOrders which have exact the same properties but ImportedOrders has one more property. After import an Order gets an ImportedOrder and so I have to copy values into a new ImportedOrders object.

I have this overly ugly method I want to get rid of - preferably without reflection. I think it can be done with expressions but my using of expression trees is more than rusty.

```
    private static ImportedOrders MapNewOrder(Order order, int uebergabeNr)
    {
        return new ImportedOrders
        {
            DFÜ_PARTNER_ID = order.DFÜ_PARTNER_ID,
            KD_BESTELL_NR = order.KD_BESTELL_NR,
            BEST_DAT = order.BEST_DAT,
            LIEF_DAT = order.LIEF_DAT,
            ILN_KUNDE = order.ILN_KUNDE,
            KUNDE_NR = order.KUNDE_NR,
            ILN_RG_EMPFG = order.ILN_RG_EMPFG,
            RG_EMPFG_NR = order.RG_EMPFG_NR,
            ILN_LIEFERANT = order.ILN_LIEFERANT,

            // ... 30 more properties ...

            Uebergabe_Nr = uebergabeNr // < the only difference
        };
    }
```

**EDIT:**

After using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) as suggested by [Amittai Shapira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169672/amittai-shapira), the relevant logic now looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, ImportedOrders>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Uebergabe_Nr, mo => mo.UseValue(uebergabeNr));
```

That's what I call an improvement :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [AutoMapper](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/), I think this is what you're after...

Comment: That one looks very promising. I will give it a try.

Comment: btw, It probably use reflection (haven't looked at the code), but the interface is nice and clean, and works...